# Why don't events appear in GIS?

Tags: dhis2

I'm using dhis2 version 22.2.
I try to show an event on the gis page.
I create a program witout registration with a stage I checked the Capture coordinates box. I register an event with the coordinate but when I want to show the event in the gis, I select the program with the organisation unit and the date, it tells me that "No event coordinates found."
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to regenerate the analytics tables for this to take effect in the GIS module. This goes for all analysis apps in DHIS 2, such as pivot table and data visualizer. To generate analytics tables, go to Reports > Analytics. You can schedule the analytics tables to run periodically from Data administration > Scheduling.